# Add 'explain' information for custom resource definition in K8S

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I've registered custom resource definition in K8S:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: resources.example.com
  labels:
    service: "my-resource"
spec:
  group: example.com
  version: v1alpha1
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    plural: resources
    singular: resource
    kind: MYRESOURCE
    shortNames:
    - res
```

Now on attempt to get an 'explain' for my custom resource with:

```
kubectl explain resource
```

I get the following error:

```
group example.com has not been registered
```

How can I add an `explain` information to my custom resource definition, or is this not supported for CRDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

explain works using openapi schema information published by the server. Prior to v1.15, CRDs did not have the ability to publish that info.

In 1.15+, CRDs that specify [structural schemas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#specifying-a-structural-schema) and [enable pruning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#pruning-versus-preserving-unknown-fields) publish OpenAPI and work with explain.

Comment: Is this still valid  with k8s 1.14 / 1.15?

Comment: in 1.15+ CRDs that specify [structural schemas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#specifying-a-structural-schema) and [enable pruning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#pruning-versus-preserving-unknown-fields) can publish OpenAPI and work with explain